# HTML and webbrowser

Tags: codenameone

I tried to use html page in my code for that i found way from kichensink application, i am using same code and same page.html file applicatin working on simulator but not working on devices. Ondevices i got a blank screen. Below is my code. Please help me on this.

```
void ShowForm()
{
    Form f = new Form("testweb");
    Container cnt = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    cnt = createDemo();
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
    f.show();
}

public Container createDemo() {
    Container cnt = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    final WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    if(wb.getInternal() instanceof BrowserComponent) {
        Button btn = new Button("Add");
        final TextArea content = new TextArea();
        Container north = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        north.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);
        north.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, btn);
        cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, north);
        content.setHint("Add to web document");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).execute("fnc('" + content.getText() + "');");
            }
        });
        ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).setBrowserNavigationCallback(new BrowserNavigationCallback() {
            public boolean shouldNavigate(String url) {
                if(url.startsWith("http://sayhello")) {
                    // warning!!! This is not on the EDT and this method MUST return immediately!
                    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ((BrowserComponent)wb.getInternal()).execute("fnc('this was written by Java code!');");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
    wb.setURL("jar:///page.html");
    return cnt;
}
```

Hi,I did few changes setlayout for container and add to another cotainer with scrollable true for container and scrollable false for form but now it's giving me error on devices and error is: "web page not available" page.html not found. Whereas page.html is already placed in src with .res file and application on simulator working fine.

Regards,
Jeny

Comment: Actually it's showing "cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, north);" up to this but on center potion when we add web browser ("cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);") that portion not coming on screen it's just show one white line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a border layout scrollable, including nested scrollables and scrolling native+Codename One widgets in sync is probably not a good idea.

Which device are you having a problem on? There was an issue with browser component on Android for some use cases, its fixed now.

Comment: Hi Almong, I am using android build for my android devices(Samsung GT-I5801). Please let me know how i can fixed this issue as it's giving me error for page.htm not found.

Comment: It seems you have a lowercase p in your URL check the case of your filename.